# What is difference between FID and OID in ArcGIS platform?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-platform

What is the main difference between OID and FID in Esri software?

Answer (score 22):

**OBJECTID**, **OID** and **FID** refer to an unique identifier of an object within a table. **FID** is the name primarily used in shapefiles (**OID** for plain DBF tables), and **OBJECTID** is at home in geodatabases (for both object classes and feature classes).

Answer (score 13):

They mean the same thing except that FID applies only to feature classes while OID (object ID) applies to object classes, which includes feature classes and tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can get both in one dataset by using tools that export/import/re-create (a process that creates a new one) your files.

You will notice an asterisk * next to one of them (usually first in attribute list) when viewing in the attribute table. The other can be deleted (unless you use it for something else).

There is only ever one internal ID field in use on any feature table.

Here are some Help 10 links.

[Gdb Field Data Types](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000001m000000.htm)

[Defining Fields in Tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000000n000000.htm)

[How Data Converts When Importing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000004q000000.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered concisely by ESRI on this page:

http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010834

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/254517/edit) your answer. We are looking explanation into the answer, not a link-only response. The URL can change and the answer can be lost

Comment: Could someone with sufficient reputation to add comments to other answers or original question please paste this as a comment to the question or one of the answers and then delete my answer? It was brought to my attention that this answer lacks enough elaboration to be an answer itself, but I think the link might still be useful to others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the terms "FID" and "OID" are entangled in that the value returned by:
arcpy.Describe(layer).FIDset
is a semicolon-separated list of values in the layer's OID field for the currently selected rows in that layer.
The name of the field that is that layer's OID field (i.e. the field that contains the values in the FIDset) is obtained by:
arcpy.Describe(layer).OIDFieldName